# create before header procees in zero pages of oracle apex

Tags: oracle-apex

I want to add a process in before header of zero oage. but it has not this event.
i neet to set value a page item in before header.
zero page has before header or not? if yes , how we can use it?
I am using apex 23.1

add a comput process

Comment: There's no such a thing on Page 0. Where is that item located? On Page 0? Would "Page load" dynamic action do?

Comment: yeah my page item is in  zero page.
page load does not work for first loading page , just work after refresh page.

Comment: Page load is *page load* regardless of when it happens. Page loads for the first time, as well as any other time (refresh is included). So, I presume that it is about something else. Perhaps you should post some more info about what you are doing, including code you used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use a variable across pages, then consider using an *Application Item* instead of a *Page Item*. Application items are defined as shared components since they are shared between pages. An application item can be set in multiple ways, but for your question the following are relevant:

1. A Computation (shared components > Computations) for the application item with a computation point of "Before Header".
2. An Application Process (Shared Components > Application Processes) with a process point of "On Load: Before Header (page template header)"